# I need to compare the difference between arbitrary version of source side by side using toirtoisegit

Tags: git, perforce, tortoisegit, p4v

I have used perforce (P4V) before, which gives a cool versions history and any version of the source can be dragged and compared between each other. The differences shown or side by side and is evry easy to track. is there something similar that can be expected using tortoise for git ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found it. This is  what i did =>  right click on the file (whose versions has to be compared) tortoiseGit>Showlog from the select the versions to be compared holding the ctr key from the revsion tree, and say compare.